# Firestore - Query with cursor and range operators

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working in Python 3.7 and I have a problem with Firestore, I'm trying to do a range query where the fields for this are inside a map called "time" in the document. The problem is that the official documentation says that different fields cannot be used in a query with range operators.

> [You can perform range (<, <=, >, >=) or not equals (!=) comparisons only on a single field](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries)

The map field:

```
time: {from: 1030 (number), to: 1600 (number)} (map)
```

So I can't do:

```
def get_docs(time):
    docs_ref = client.collection("COLLECTION_NAME") \
        .where("time.from", "<=", time) \
        .where("time.to", ">=", time)
```

So I tried a workaround using a cursor, let me show you an example:

```
def get_cursor(time):
    cursor_ref = client.collection("COLLECTION_NAME") \
        .order_by("time.to", direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING) \
        .where("time.to", ">=", time) \
        .limit(1)

    cursor_docs = cursor_ref.get()

    for cursor in cursor_docs:
        return cursor


def get_docs(time):
    cursor = get_cursor(time)

    docs_ref = client.collection("COLLECTION_NAME") \
        .order_by("time.to", direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING) \
        .start_at(cursor) \
        .where("time.from", "<=", time)

    docs = docs_ref.get()
```

I can get the correct cursor but when y try to use it in the get_docs function with the where clause "time.from" and the range operator <= I get an empty result. But when I use the range operator >= I get docs in the result, but not the expected ones obviously.

Use case:

```
documents:
    doc1 => time: {from: 1030, to: 1600}
    doc2 => time: {from: 1000, to: 1300}
    doc3 => time: {from: 1200, to: 1900}
    doc4 => time: {from: 1100, to: 1700}

documents order_by time.to ascending:
    doc2 => time: {from: 900, to: 1000}
    doc1 => time: {from: 1030, to: 1600}
    doc4 => time: {from: 1100, to: 1700}
    doc3 => time: {from: 1200, to: 1900}

time = 1100

get_cursor(time) => doc1

get_docs(time):
    expected result: {doc1, doc4}
    obtained result: {}
```

I don't know if the limitations of the range operators affect even through a cursor, if this is the case, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your example and I found this error

`400 inequality filter property and first sort order must be the same: time.from and time.to`

This is because only `where` operators are allowed on the field used for the `order_by` operation.

Playing with the main logic of your query

```
client.collection("COLLECTION_NAME") \
        .where("time.from", "<=", time) \
        .where("time.to", ">=", time)
```

And according to your dataset `from` is always lower than `to`

- First I will try to get the last item `cursor` where the condition `<=` over `from` field is valid
- After that I will try to get the items where condition `>=` over the field `to` is valid and the search will stop when found the cursor (latest valid document).

```py
from google.cloud import firestore

db = firestore.Client()
col = db.collection("dates")


def get_cursor(time):
    cursor_ref = col\
        .order_by("time.from", direction=firestore.Query.DESCENDING)\
        .where("time.from", "<=", time).limit(1)
    docs = cursor_ref.stream()

    for doc in docs:
        return doc


def get_docs(time):
    cursor = get_cursor(time)

    docs_ref = col \
        .order_by("time.to", direction=firestore.Query.ASCENDING) \
        .end_at(cursor)\
        .where("time.to", ">=", time)

    docs = docs_ref.stream()
    for doc in docs:
        print(doc.to_dict())


get_docs(1100)
```

This are my results (`from`<= 1100 & `to` >=1100)

```
{'time': {'from': 1000, 'to': 1300}}
{'time': {'from': 1030, 'to': 1600}}
{'time': {'from': 1100, 'to': 1700}}
```

Comment: You're right, the error was due to not having a `where` with the `order_by` field. I am using the emulator and that error did not show it for some reason.
Otherwise, in your response the `get_docs` function sorts by the field `to` that is not the same one used to obtain the cursor `from`, this will return a list of documents in a different order and the cursor will be located in an X position that could leave out valid documents.

Comment: @federicoforzano the elements will be ordered different because we have different filters (same data), but this approach works because it is only necessary to know when stop the second query (cursor)

please try this approach with some data and tell me if this works